# MongoDB update where multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to update information on one of my fields where two different conditions are met. I don't know if this is the right idea on how to do it, but guidance would be appreciated. I am met with the error of: "unknown top level operator: $eq"

```
db.shop.update({"$and":[{"item.name":"Milk"}, {"$eq":{"item.price":2.80}}]}, {"$set": {"item.expiry":"21/10/19"}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $and as

```
db.shop.update(
  {"$and":[{"$eq":["item.name","Milk"]}, {"$eq":["item.price",2.80]}]}, 
  {"$set": {"item.expiry":"21/10/19"}}
)

but it is equivalent to below and will be faster as expression takes time to compute

db.shop.update(
 {"item.name":"Milk","item.price":2.80}, 
 {"$set": {"item.expiry":"21/10/19"}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$eq` and `$and` and just use the following query.

```
db
  .shop
  .update({
    "item.name": "Milk",
    "item.price": 2.80
  }, {
    "$set": {
      "item.expiry": "21/10/19"
    }
  });
```